# How do I manage this invisible gap between content?

Tags: css

I have a fairly simple page with images that link to downloadable documents. I have one section that floats left and the other that floats right followed by an empty div to clear both before I add more content.

The problem is that there is an unwanted 100px gap between the first set of forms and the General Forms section.

Here is the page: http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/forms/

Here is the html:

```
<div class="forms-nc">
<h2>Forms for OHS Durham, NC Patients</h2>

<div class="form-box">      
<a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/nc_downloads/OHS_CF1402_NP_Questionnaire.pdf""><img class="forms" src="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/photos/btn_new-patients.jpg" alt="PDF Form" /></a>
<p><a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/nc_downloads/OHS_CF1402_NP_Questionnaire.pdf"">New Patient Questionnaire</a></p>
</div>

<div class="form-box">      
<a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/nc_downloads/OHS_CF1401_Directions_to_907_Broad_St.pdf"><img class="forms" src="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/photos/btn_directions.jpg" alt="PDF Form" /></a>

<p><a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/nc_downloads/OHS_CF1401_Directions_to_907_Broad_St.pdf">Driving Directions</a></p>
</div>

</div>  

<div id="forms-me">
<h2>Forms for OHS Maine Patients</h2>

<div class="form-box">      
<a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/hi_downloads/NP_questionnaire_Maine.pdf"><img class="forms" src="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/photos/btn_new-patients.jpg" alt="PDF Form" /></a>
<p><a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/hi_downloads/NP_questionnaire_Maine.pdf">New Patient Questionnaire</a></p>

</div>

<div class="form-box">      
<a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/hi_downloads/OHS-ME_Directions.pdf"><img class="forms" src="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/photos/btn_directions.jpg" alt="PDF Form" /></a>
<p><a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/hi_downloads/OHS-ME_Directions.pdf">Driving Directions</a></p>
</div>

</div> 


<div class="more"></div>
<h2>General Forms for All Patients</h2>

<div class="form-box">      
<a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/nc_downloads/Herb_Cooking_instructions.pdf"><img class="forms" src="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/photos/btn_herbs.jpg" alt="PDF Form" /></a>

<p><a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/nc_downloads/Herb_Cooking_instructions.pdf">Herb Cooking Instructions</a></p>
</div>          

<div class="form-box">      
<a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/documents/Basal_Chart.pdf"><img class="forms" src="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/photos/btn_bbt.jpg" alt="PDF Form" /></a>
<p><a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/documents/Basal_Chart.pdf">Basal Body Temperature Chart</a></p>
</div>          

<div class="form-box">      
<a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/hi_downloads/Food_Inventory.pdf"><img class="forms" src="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/photos/btn_food.jpg" alt="PDF Form" /></a>
<p><a href="http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/images/uploads/hi_downloads/Food_Inventory.pdf">Food Inventory Chart</a></p>

</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.forms-nc               { width: 350px; height: 450px; float: left; border-right: 3px solid ; border-color: #ff2500; }
#forms-me               { width: 300px; height: 450px; float: left; margin-left: 50px;  }

#forms #main_content a  { 
    margin-left: 20px;
 } 

#forms #main_content h2 { 
    text-align: center;
 }

#forms #main_content a.title { 
    text-align: center;
 } 

body#forms-2 div.forms  { float: left; height: 1050px;  } 
.form-box               { float: left; width: 180px; height: 190px; margin-right: 20px; } 
.form-box img.forms     { margin: 5px 0 0 80px; }
.form-box p             { margin: 0 0 0 50px; padding: 0; width: 178px; height: 15px; text-align: center; }
.more                   { width: 600px; height: 5px; clear: both; }
```

I have tried a negative margin and it doesn't budge. I would appreciate any help to clear this up!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your:

```
<div class="more"></div>
```

before the General Forms section. It has a `clear: both` so it is always below the image on the left-hand side menu. If you disable javascript you'll see that the gap is even bigger as the menu is a lot higher.

What you could do, is wrap both `forms-nc` and `forms-me` in another div and give that div a `overflow: hidden` so that it wraps around both inner divs. Then you can get rid of the `.more` div and the General Forms section will line up directly under the wrapper div.

Comment: jeroen, nothing short of brilliant. Thank you for taking the time to diagnose the problem and offer a good solution.